# Add circle around a div

Tags: html, css, dom

I have this div that looks like a big square but I would like to add a little circle on the top of the div (keeping the style) with an icon inside (I mean something like Font Awesome) so people will know what category of content it is.

How can I do that using css ?

Thank you

```css
.le_quiz {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px #40c8d6;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.le_quiz .post-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #404040;
}

.le_quiz .postbody {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.le_quiz .postbody a:visited {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color:#404040;
}
.le_quiz .cta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#38C8D6;
}
.le_quiz .cta:visited {
  color:#38C8D6;
}
```

```html
<div class="le_quiz">
</div>
```

This is what I'd like : [Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYv8N.png)

Comment: can you show an example or draw a picture of what you're trying to do? what font awesome icon are you referring to?

Comment: Oops yes sorry @MichaelCoker

Comment: @MichaelCoker I'm sorry I forgot, is there any way to add an icon inside the circle and position it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 pseudo elements. One to put the circle up top, and the other to cover the bottom half of the circle.

```css
.le_quiz {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px #40c8d6;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.le_quiz .post-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #404040;
}

.le_quiz .postbody {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.le_quiz .postbody a:visited {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color:#404040;
}
.le_quiz .cta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#38C8D6;
}
.le_quiz .cta:visited {
  color:#38C8D6;
}

.le_quiz:before, .le_quiz:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
}

.le_quiz:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.le_quiz:after {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="le_quiz">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another div and set boder-radius to 50% to make it a circle.

```css
.le_quiz, .circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px #40c8d6;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.le_quiz .post-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #404040;
}

.le_quiz .postbody {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.le_quiz .postbody a:visited {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color:#404040;
}
.le_quiz .cta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#38C8D6;
}
.le_quiz .cta:visited {
  color:#38C8D6;
}
.circle {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  top: 100px;
  left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="le_quiz">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @KrisRoofe ! Is there any way to make it look like there is no shadow so we think it's the same div ?